# MATLAB Expanding A Matrix with Zeros

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I need a matrix of `nxn`, where the first `pxp` of it contains ones and rest are zeros. I can do it with traversing the cells, so I'm not asking a way to do it. I'm looking for "the *MATLAB* way" to do it, using built-in functions and avoiding loops etc.

To be more clear;

let `n=4 and p=2`,

then the expected result is:

```
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

There are possibly more than one elegant solution to do it, so I will accept the answer with the shortest and most readable one.

P.S. The question title looks a bit irrelevant: I put that title because my initial approach would be creating a `pxp` matrix with ones, then expanding it to `nxn` with zeros.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is creating a matrix of zeroes, and then setting part of it to `1` using indexing:

For example:

```
n = 4;
p = 2;
x = zeros(n,n);
x(1:p,1:p) = 1;
```

If you insist on expanding, you can use:

```
padarray( zeros(p,p)+1 , [n-p n-p], 0, 'post')
```

Comment: `padarray( ones(p,p) , [n-p n-p], 0, 'post')` is also working, thanks for teaching me `padarray` function.

Comment: NB: `padarray` requires the Image Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to expand the matrix with **zeros**:

```
>> p = 2; n = 4;
>> M = ones(p,p)
M =
     1     1
     1     1
>> M(n,n) = 0
M =
     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the matrix easily by concatenating horizontally and vertically:

```
n = 4;
p = 2;
MyMatrix = [ ones(p), zeros(p, n-p); zeros(n-p, n) ];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>> p = 2; n = 4;
>> a = [ones(p, 1); zeros(n - p, 1)]

a =

     1
     1
     0
     0

>> A = a * a'

A =

     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```